# scalaz.State stack overflow in deep monadic loop

Tags: scala, stack-overflow, scalaz, state-monad

I'm experimenting with different implementation of [Depth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) with [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz).

This traverse should handle wide along with deep tree-like structures.

Main idea - subordinate elements should be generated according to some "state". For example set of **marked as seen** elements to avoid them in future.

Here the simplest implementation I've come with

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.syntax.monad._
import scalaz.State._

abstract class DepthFirstState[E, S] {
  def build(elem: E): State[S, List[E]]

  def go(start: E): State[S, List[E]] = for {
    xs ← build(start)
    ys ← xs.traverseSTrampoline(go)
  } yield start :: ys.flatten
}
```

We can create the simplest algorithm to test how it handle deep search

```
class RangeSearchState extends DepthFirstState[Int, Int] {
  def build(elem: Int) = get[Int] map (limit ⇒ if (elem < limit) List(elem + 1) else Nil)
}
```

It's just a tree degraded to linked list,  where each element `i` has single child `i+1` until it reaches `limit` encoded in state. While state is not changing it's more `Reader` than `State` but it's not the case.

Now

```
new RangeSearchState go 1 run 100
```

Successfully builds traversed number list. While

```
new RangeSearchState go 1 run 1000
```

Falling with `StackOverflowError`.

Is there way to fix implementation of `DepthFirstState` so it could run without `StackOverflow` even on very deep recursion?

Comment: I'll just leave it here http://blog.higher-order.com/assets/trampolines.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trampolining that happens in `traverseSTrampoline` protects you from overflowing the stack during the traversal. So for example this explodes:

```
import scalaz._, scalaz.std.list._, scalaz.syntax.traverse._

(0 to 10000).toList.traverseU(_ => State.get[Unit]).run(())
```

While this doesn't (note that `traverseS` is the same as `traverseSTrampoline` for `State`):

```
(0 to 10000).toList.traverseS(_ => State.get[Unit]).run(())
```

You only get this protection during the traversal, though, and in your case the overflow is happening because of the recursive call. You can fix this by doing the trampolining manually:

```
import scalaz._
import scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

abstract class DepthFirstState[E, S] {
  type TState[s, a] = StateT[Free.Trampoline, s, a]

  def build(elem: E): TState[S, List[E]]

  def go(start: E): TState[S, List[E]] = for {
    xs <- build(start)
    ys <- xs.traverseU(go)
  } yield start :: ys.flatten
}

class RangeSearchState extends DepthFirstState[Int, Int] {
  def build(elem: Int): TState[Int, List[Int]] =
    MonadState[TState, Int].get.map(limit =>
      if (elem < limit) List(elem + 1) else Nil
    )
}
```

And then:

```
val (state, result) = (new RangeSearchState).go(1).run(10000).run
```

It's worth noting that this stack safety is built into `State` in [cats](https://github.com/non/cats):

```
import cats.state.State
import cats.std.function._, cats.std.list._
import cats.syntax.traverse._

abstract class DepthFirstState[E, S] {
  def build(elem: E): State[S, List[E]]

  def go(start: E): State[S, List[E]] = for {
    xs <- build(start)
    ys <- xs.traverseU(go)
  } yield start :: ys.flatten
}

class RangeSearchState extends DepthFirstState[Int, Int] {
  def build(elem: Int): State[Int, List[Int]] =
    State.get[Int].map(limit => if (elem < limit) List(elem + 1) else Nil)
}

val (state, result) = (new RangeSearchState).go(1).run(10000).run
```

This safe-by-default choice is discussed in some detail [here](https://github.com/non/cats/issues/122).

Comment: I have similar problems with `StreamT`. Could it be that `Free.Trampoline` will help here too?

Comment: @Odomontois Yes, it's likely.

Comment: scalaz 7.2 will have a stack-safe StateT by default and a BindRec type-class, which abstracts over stack-safe monadic recursion.